# Optimum algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Two workers has several tasks.Assume the tasks has duration of 14, 7, 2, 4. The next task goes to first worker that is free. The two workers have to finish several tasks in one day. The same task takes the same time on the two workers. Our goal is to finish the tasks as soon as possible.

Two questions:
1.show that the algorithm always completes the task prior to time 2*T,T is the optimum completion time.
2.express the optimum scheduling with a resursion(multi-dimentonal)

Not HW PRoblem

Please give me some suggestions

What is  a multi-dimentional recursion?

Comment: The question is a little too hard to understand.  "T is the optimum completion time": optimum in what case?  And multi-dimensional recursion?  If it's not a homework problem, then what are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @Justin: I'm guessing optimum of all possible arrangements.

Comment: Achieving time 2*T is trivial. Just have one worker do everything, since the optimum time cannot be less than half of the total time for all tasks.

Comment: Clarification on previous comment: any order of the tasks will achieve time less than 2*T, since the optimum time T is at least 1/2 the total of all tasks.

Comment: Just curious, if it is "Not HW PRoblem", then where did it come from?  People don't phrase their own questions this way.

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask for suggestions...

Try drawing the problem out.  Have a timeline for worker #1 and worker #2 and specify what tasks they are working on for what stretches of time.  Once you understand why this algorithm completes in less than 2*T time, you then can start figuring out how to formally prove it.